# Multiple new returns of Scanner from a single method

Tags: java, class, methods, java.util.scanner

to make my code cleaner I was wondering if I could separate the scanner inputs to a different method. Yet, as soon as I did it, I ran into many errors and am unable to perform the tasks.

Code for main:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Task taskObject = new Task();

    taskObject.taskInput();
    taskObject.taskOutput(id, keyword, price);
}
```

Code for Task class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Task{
    public task taskInput(){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("\nEnter the id: ");
        int id = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("\nEnter the keyword: ");
        String keyword = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("\nEnter the price: ");
        double price = scan.nextDouble();

        return task(id, keyword, price);
    }

    public void taskOutput(int id, String keyword, double price){       
        System.out.println(id);
        System.out.println(keyword);
        System.out.println(price);
    }
}
```

Comment: What error exactly are you getting?

Comment: TaskMain.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
                newTask.taskOutput(id, keyword, price);
                                   ^
  symbol:   variable id
  location: class TaskMain

And I get this for all the variables.

Comment: `id`, `keyword`, and `price` are out of scope in `main()`. And I'm guessing you don't have a type called `task`. Even if you did, you're missing the `new` keyword to instantiate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`id`, `keyword` and `price` are local variables in the scope of `taskInput`, and you cannot relate to them after the method has terminated. One possible approach would be to make the `Task` object stateful, and save them as members:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Task{
    private int id;
    private String keyword;
    private double price;

    public void taskInput(){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("\nEnter the id: ");
        id = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("\nEnter the keyword: ");
        keyword = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("\nEnter the price: ");
        price = scan.nextDouble();
    }

    public void taskOutput() {
        // Note that id, keyword and price are now members       
        System.out.println(id);
        System.out.println(keyword);
        System.out.println(price);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Task taskObject = new Task();

        taskObject.taskInput();
        taskObject.taskOutput();
    }
}
```

Comment: But how can I the separate the the task class from the class the main method is in (say, taskmain class)?

Comment: @JakeMedlow with his change, `Task` becomes fully self contained, and the `main` method just creates an instance and calls method on it. You can move this `main` method to wherever you want. I just placed it in `Task` for convenience, but it really doesn't matter.